# authors with multiple papers, possessive (genitive) form of citation command

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm having difficulties of citing author which has multiple papers (different years) with possessive (genitive) case. I want the citation like

> Smith's (1997,2001).

I manage to have

> Smith's (1997),

but not for

> Smith's (1997,2001).

I use `natbib`, the new command i use is:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
 \newcommand\citeapos[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
```

Can anyone assist me on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution: Make `\citeapos` take *two* arguments: the first will be fed to `\citeauthor`, the second to `\citeyear`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand\citeapos[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#2})}
```

Proposed usage: `\citeapos{smith97}{smith97,smith01}`.

(I tried creating a macro that extracts the first key (i.e., everything up to the first comma) from `smith97,smith01` and passes the result to `\citeauthor`. However, I kept getting errors of the form `Argument of \@citex has an extra }`.  That's why I'm proposing setting up a two-argument macro to handle genitive-case citation callouts.)